# Is there a way to pass multiple streams into a StreamProvider in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter app with multiple collections on Firestore. I am consuming the data streams in a StreamProvider and would like to listen to multiple streams in the Streamprovider 'value'. Is there a way of achieving this.

My getters are

```
  // GET USER DATA
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get userData {
    return userCollection.snapshots();
  }


  // FETCHING STUDENT DATA
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get studentData {
    return studentCollection.snapshots();
  }
```

My Stream provider is:

```
return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
  value: DatabaseService().userData,
  initialData: null,
 child: Widget()

 );
```

How can I listen to the studentData?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to merge those streams, for example by using [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html)